# Remove all rows following first row with all NA's

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
col1<-c("one", NA,"three",NA,"four","five")
col2<-c("fish", "cat","dog",NA,"deer","fox")
(df<-as.data.frame(cbind(col1,col2), stringsAsFactors = F))
   col1 col2
1   one fish
2  <NA>  cat
3 three  dog
4  <NA> <NA>
5  four deer
6  five  fox
```

I would like to remove all the rows following the first row that has all NA's (and the NA row itself too). My expected result:

```
   col1 col2
1   one fish
2  <NA>  cat
3 three  dog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `rowSums` and `cumsum`.

```
df[cumsum(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df)) == 0, ]

#   col1 col2
#1   one fish
#2  <NA>  cat
#3 three  dog
```

To understand this one-liner we can break it down step by step

```
rowSums(is.na(df))
#[1] 0 1 0 2 0 0

rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

cumsum(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df))
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

and now filter only those rows with 0.

---

Or another alternative with `which.max` which would return index of first `TRUE` value

```
df[1:(which.max(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df)) - 1), ]

#   col1 col2
#1   one fish
#2  <NA>  cat
#3 three  dog
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one base R option which finds all indices of rows having one or more `NA` values.  Then, it finds the second to smallest index such index, and subsets the original data frame to include all rows up to, but not including, that second to smallest `NA` index.

```
na_index <- which(rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0)                # rows with one or more NA
keep_index <- min(na_index[na_index != min(na_index)])   # second to last NA index
df[1:(keep_index-1), ]                                   # subset data frame

   col1 col2
1   one fish
2  <NA>  cat
3 three  dog
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. Your code works well for my sample data but unfortunately does not in the original data

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different base solution could be:

```
df[1:nrow(df) < min(which(rowSums(is.na(df[, 1:length(df)])) == length(df))), ]

   col1 col2
1   one fish
2  <NA>  cat
3 three  dog
```

It, first, identifies the smallest row number where the number of missing values is equal to the number of variables. Then, it subsets the data by keeping only rows that are under the row number given the condition.

Or the same with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 filter(row_number() < min(which(rowSums(is.na(.[, 1:length(.)])) == length(.))))
```